# Merge two stackoverflow users

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, user-accounts

I have somehow created two separate users in stackoverflow.  I think this is because the first one I setup didn't actually register as a full user, and that computer doesn't exist anymore, so the cookies are gone forever.  I've set up an account again, but reputation is back at 1 and I'm listed twice in the users list.  Can I merge the two users together somehow?

Comment: belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: What do you mean, "doesn't exist anymore"? Sounds like a rather violent way for a computer to go.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are 3 of them ;-p

I've confirmed identity between 2 of them via private details (not shown on the public profile); merged. I wonder whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151644/bruce-chapman) is you as well, though.