# Merging posts from my unregistered era

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts

First I was an unregistered user and now I am being a registered user but my previous posts are not available with this. As my unregistered and registered user name are the same how do I get it?

Is it possible or not to include all previous posts to my registered user account?

Comment: Looks like a similar situation to [this user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22328/merge-two-stackoverflow-users)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer (score 1):

A moderator can merge the accounts for you, but there are quite a few users with your display name. They might be able to figure it out just from access logs, but to be safe, can you include the user ID of the other account that needs to be merged?

Target: [439582](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439582/mahesh)

Source: ???

Comment: sir how can i put the id on my previous unregister user profile?

Comment: @ChrisF If you are referring to using the User list on the appropriate site, [that does not list unregistered users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49764/is-there-a-way-to-sift-through-a-list-of-unregistered-users/49768#49768). But diamonds and above do have the ability to search for a user, so what should be done is the user should flag a post for moderator attention and note the username for the other account.

Comment: @Grace - good point. Comment deleted.

Comment: Sent a list of links to the posts you make as different users, that should let the mods find all the user ids.